# Anyone please write a sub class of Bus and Racing Car

Tags: java

Following is the abstract class of Vehicle with two abstract methods.

```
abstract class Vehicle {
String VehicleName;
intnumofGears;
String color;
abstractbooleanhasDiskBrake();
abstractintgetNoofGears();
}
```

Implement the above class in sub class of Bus and Racing Car. Provide the implementation of abstract methods in these classes.
Assume a Bus has Five gears (4+1)4 forward, 1 Reverse Gear. It has Disk Brake mounted on all the wheels. Assume Racing Car has seven number of Gears (6+1) 6 forward, 1 Reverse and Disk brakes mounted on the front wheels of car only.

So anyone please help me to write this program,

Comment: keyword abstract is  required

Comment: I am not good in Java, so will you please write a small example of the above

Comment: Have you tried something ? Witch part are you stuck on ?

Comment: @StanlyStephen what i said is `abstractbooleanhasDiskBrake()` should be `abstract void abstractbooleanhasDiskBrake();`

Comment: @StanlyStephen this is easy and you should do your self .this is good tutorial which is very close to your question http://www.wideskills.com/java-tutorial/java-abstract-class-and-interface and https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial Bus class, you should be able to use it to write RacingCar.

```
class Bus extends Vehicle {
    String VehicleName;
    final int numofGears = 5;
    String color;

    boolean hasDiskBrake() {
        return true;
    }

    int getNoofGears() {
        return numofGears;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @unkhan and FastSnail